# did either side take prisoners of war in the Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, war

The concept was known at that time:

> Then Pandu’s five sons defeated Drupada in battle. Taking
> him and his advisers prisoners

What did both sides do with enemy soldiers who surrendered?

Comment: Interesting question, but this war was special (not general one) you see. It was basically kinda civil war. Pāṇḍavas were from the Kuruvaṁśa only and not exactly foes of the Kauravas. And with the defeat of the Kaurava army, Yudhiṣṭhira (son of Pāṇdu) became King of Kauravas. So, even the defeated soldiers of Kaurava army (that fought Pāṇḍavas and survived till end) would be in the service of Kauravas only. They aren't required, nor is there any need for them to be prisoners. As for the allies who fought for the Kaurava army, they would still remain allies, and don't need to be prisoners.

Comment: As I have stated above, there was no need for Yudhiṣṭhira to take any prisoners of war upon victory, for both armies came under him, upon becoming King. As for the Kaurava army, they had already lost the battle. The Kaurava army surrendered at the end, when Duryodhana was defeated in a mace battle. And the army of Pāṇḍavas won, they didn't surrender (they only had casualties).